# What does it mean domain module in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

What does it mean domain module in Angular?

Also is it possible to group all additional custom classes like Helpers to module?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/module-types). Also, sure.  What specifically are you having an issue with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain feature modules deliver a user experience dedicated to a particular application domain like editing a customer or placing an order.

They typically have a top component that acts as the feature root and private, supporting sub-components descend from it.

Domain feature modules consist mostly of declarations. Only the top component is exported.

Domain feature modules rarely have providers. When they do, the lifetime of the provided services should be the same as the lifetime of the module.

Domain feature modules are typically imported exactly once by a larger feature module.

They might be imported by the root AppModule of a small application that lacks routing.

https://angular.io/guide/module-types

Answer (score -1):

I very frequently create a module in my large projects that just contains all of my common classes/pipes/components/directives etc. Then I usually just import that module into my other modules. Here is an example:

```js
@NgModule({
    declaration: [
        MyPipePipe
    ],
    exports: [
        MyPipePipe
    ]
})
export class CommonClassModule {}
```

you just need to make sure that whatever module or anything you want to use in your other modules are placed in the `exports` array

CHEERS!

Comment: What does this have to do with what is a domain module?